# How to download all HTTP files from a server

Tags: webserver, http

I have to do some work on one website, for example `example.com`, but I need to acces some HTTP sites (`example.com/example.htm`, `example.com/example2`, …)

I don't know how are they named) but I dont know how to access them. Is there a way I can download everything from that FTP server that is not mine?

I have no access to the FTP server. Imagine that it is blank website with no buttons or anything (`example.com`), but there are some files and websites on that same server. I need to know all these files.

Comment: Your question isn't entirely clear. How do you connect to the FTP server? Did you try an FTP client program? Do you even know that there's an FTP service running there?

Comment: I have no access to the FTP server. Imagine that it is blank website with no buttons or anything (example.com), but there are some files and websites on that same server (example.com/example.pdf or example.htp). I need to know all these files.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to the FTP server (which basically just gives you access to the file system that the HTTP server is pointing at), and you don't know what the files are called, then you have no other choice than [brute-forcing](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Forced_browsing) all [possible URLs](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Path_Traversal) via HTTP requests, in the hope that they give you something back.

Of course, this is not very practical, but if the server provides no directory listing, you're out of luck.

Note that depending on how that server is set up, your client may also be blocked from making too many connections.